# Adding domain to Google Cloud Storage hosted web-app

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps, google-cloud-storage

I am new to Google Cloud Storage.

I want to try Google Cloud Storage to host my web-app. Is it possible to upload my website to Google Cloud Storage and connect own domain without Google Apps premium subscription?
If yes, please check my steps below, how I tried to make it works, and let me know where I where wrong?

1. I have created Cloud Console project for my web-app. My Project ID: rippl-io
2. Then linked the domain of the web-app to existing Google Apps account as a secondary (as I were redirected to Google Apps after trying to add new domain from the cloud console). Domain name I am going to use: rippl.io
3. In App Engine settings in Google Apps I am clicking "Add new url" and selecting rippl.io domain. But it returns error.

I am guessing I can add only primary domain and that must be a reason of error. So, next, to change rippl.io to primary domain I need to upgrade Google Apps to premium. Are any other ways to add own domain to my website on Google Cloud Storage other than buying premium Google Apps?

Comment: Can you provide some more information as to what you are trying to do?  Are you thinking you can actually hosting a pre-existing website on Google Cloud Storage?  Or are you trying to use the cloud storage as the database that houses your web site's data?

Comment: @Derek ,Existing website. I want to change hosting to Google Cloud and connect domain as well

Answer (score 1):

To add domain @ Google Cloud Storage, first you need to verify it from Google Webmaster Tools, then create a bucket exactly matching your domain name e.g. `www.example.com` upload your data, files etc, then add `CNAME`entry `www.example.com IN CNAME c.storage.googleapis.com.`
Please remember, Google Cloud Storage will work for plain html webpages it will not execute any server side codes like php

```
gsutil web set -m index.html -e missing.html gs://www.example.com
```

If you still have php page, you can use below code, but php code will get displayed in webpage view source, it will not get execute:

```
gsutil setmeta -h Content-Type:text/html gs://www.example.com/demo.php
```

To add domain @ Google App Engine, you need Google Apps for Business account to verify it.

Comment: Thanks I am going to try your instruction. In what cases I need to use Cloud Storage and when App Engine?

Comment: And please look on this)) http://techcrunch.com/2013/10/08/php-on-google-app-engine-now-generally-available/  @Hrishi

Comment: PHP is not working on Google Cloud Storage, above commands are for Google Cloud Storage not App Engine.

Comment: Hi @Hrishi seams it's not working for some reason. Should the name of the bucket include the "www"?  P.S. Thanks for clerification about php. I have uploaded plaint html just for current testing

Comment: `www` is not mandatory, for testing do something like create a subdomain say `test.example.com` from Google Webmaster tools add this domain and verify it. Create bucket `test.example.com` add your files and test it CNAME: `test.example.com. IN CNAME c.storage.googleapis.com.`

Comment: Hi @Hrishi, I tried two variants in CNAME and bucket: with www www.example.com and clean example.com . Both seams not working. What could be wrong?

Comment: Did you checked ping to bucket `example.com` is it getting response from `storage.l.googleusercontent.com` and have you set acl for public read `gsutil setacl public-read gs://example.com/index.html`

Comment: I didn't. Can you point me on the instruction please. I found something here https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration but can't understand everything especially step 4: "Apply a website configuration to your bucket. Based on your requirements, you can do this using the raw XML API or the gsutil tool."

Comment: I have not tried XML API, I am using gsutil tool from my Debian server, you can use this tool from any server or desktop even Windows.Above commands will do required basic setup for website as you need, try it.

Comment: I feel I am getting confused a bit. Is this step 4 is the last things I need make it works? And I have a small problem - no Windows or Mac, just Chromebook Android and iPad. Should I go to windows friend and make this on his PC, or there any ways to do it from the web?

Comment: `gsutil web set -m index.html -e missing.html gs://www.example.com` is command using gsutil tool for last step no.4: Apply a website configuration to your bucket..... https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#specifications gsutil runs on Linux/Unix, Mac OS, and Windows. Search Google for any help in installation, configuration etc, once installed, then whole task is very easy.